# windows 8 unicode input not right

Tags: windows-8, unicode

I notice that Unicode input does not work the way I would expect.

An example is the Unicode character for superscript-two (the number-"square" character), U+00B2. If I type `numeric +` + `00b2` I get "☻" (which is rendering as some dark smiley face) instead of superscript 2. This problem occurs using the Metro IE in text input fields. I get nothing at all in the URL bar. I also get nothing at all in WordPad.

Specific behaviours of various apps:

**Metro IE** has both behaviors: at the url bar it inserts nothing, but in text fields it inserts some other character (instead of the SUPERSCRIPT-TWO Unicode character "²", I get a dark smiley face: "☻").

**Desktop IE**: I get the dark smiley face both in text input fields and in the url bar.

**WordPad**: it inserts nothing.

**Core Windows 8 Search feature**: it does not work, although at least I get no input rather than the wrong Unicode character. **Maps Tile app** works perfectly though.

**Command Prompt**: Works perfectly.

**Google's Chrome Browser**: Works perfectly.

My primary input language is Singapore-English, but that should not effect this. I have `HKEY_Current_User/Control Panel/Input Method` key `EnableHexNumpad` set to "1".

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: Please clarify: Does “it works in text input fields” mean that it produces the “²” character, or that it produces “☻”? If you get nothing at all in the URL bar, when do you get “☻” then? Does this happen in all browsers?

Comment: — Korpela: it produces the smiley face in text fields, and produces no symbol in the url bar. I cannot produce the superscript two at all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue is limited to Internet Explorer. Some IE version apparently changed things so that the “Alt + hex” method only works when hex digits are typed from the numpad. This makes it impossible to use it for a character with a letter in its Unicode number in hex.

There are several workarounds for characters like superscript 2, “²”. For example, you can use the decimal number with 0 prefix: Alt 0178, provided that the input language is English. In the general case, however, I’m afraid you need a clumbsier workaround, like typing the character in another program and then using copuy & paste.

The “Alt  hex+” is old in Windows but very poorly document, apparently no public documentation by Microsoft, but described e.g. in [How to enter Unicode characters in Microsoft Windows](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm) at FileFormat.info. Normally, you can use both numpad digits and digits and letter from the normal keyboard. But this was broken, probably unintentionally, in some version of IE (IE 10?).

Comment: I don't think this is the same method that you are referring to. This is not `alt` + `hex`, this is `alt`+`numeric plus`+`hex` — and is the one documented in Wikipedia as one of 3 ways that it works. Also, I have further tried it in WordPad (with Calibri font, if that matters) and I do not see the superscript two there.

Comment: It’s the same method, we just use different notations to name it. It’s odd if it does not work in WordPad in Win 8, but perhaps Microsoft propagated the change that made IE break the method. In Win 7, the method works OK *except* in IE (all modes).

Comment: okay well, dealing with this as an answer — I don't see any way to verify that this is the answer, or what even this is: you just make an off-hand comment with no references. I think I need references, a way to verify that this is the problem, a way to verify that otherwise the input method works appropriately, and a way to resolve the problem.

Comment: You can test whether the method works in other browsers and other programs (like Notepad and Word). You can also check whether the method works in the cases you described when the hexadecimal code contains only digits 0–9. And a way to resolve the problem is to use other input methods, as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Well, your work-around works, but after looking at various parts of the system to see what has a problem and what does not, your suspicion of what the problem is seems to be wrong. I'd give you half credit if I could. :) Thanks for the help.