# Can't input GREEK Symbols with ALT+NUM on Windows8 any more

Tags: windows-8, unicode

I used to input greek symbols through ALT+NUM.

However, this way doesn't work on my new Windows8 any more.

It seems to me I can only input ASCII characters through ATL+NUM now.

I can input Φ by ALT+934 on my windows7 laptop. But it doesn't work on my Windows8 desktop.

Thanks if you know what's the problem could be? MS or my keyboard or my input method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way Alt *number* works depends on the application and on the “input language” in Microsoft terms. It seems that there have been changes in Windows 8 in this respect.

There are various workarounds. For example, for Greek letters, install the Greek keyboard layout (which is part of Windows, just not a visible option by default), switch to that layout temporarily, and use normal keys, e.g. the F key for phi (φ, Φ); check the mapping from the information available when you install the layout.

Cf. to [Which character encoding is used for ALT-codes?](https://superuser.com/questions/348674/which-character-encoding-is-used-for-alt-codes) and [Why does [ALT+224] return Ó instead of alpha?](https://superuser.com/questions/449029/why-does-alt224-return-instead-of-alpha/) and [windows 8 unicode input not right](https://superuser.com/questions/642552/windows-8-unicode-input-not-right).